# How to increase mapper quota?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am using Google App engine Mapper API to delete all rows (approx. 2M) for a particular entity in my GAE datastore. However, even though I have a billed account, I still get -

> com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.MapReduceServlet processMapper:
>   Out of mapper quota. Aborting request until quota is replenished.
>   Consider increasing mapreduce.mapper.inputprocessingrate (default
>   1000) if you would like your mapper job to complete faster.

How do I specifically increase the mapper quota? I need to remove the records urgently, but cannot find any documentation to increase mapper quota. If there is any other best practices I should be aware of, please let me know.

This is what I am doing in the mapper class.

```
  public void map(Key key, Entity value, Context context) {
    log.info("Mapping key: " + key);

    if (value.hasProperty("email")) {
        String email = (String) value.getProperty("email");
        if(email.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxx@xxxxx.com")) {
            DatastoreMutationPool mutationPool = this.getAppEngineContext(context).getMutationPool();
            mutationPool.delete(key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you yielding the delete operation in your mapper function? or just calling `db.delete()` ?

Comment: Maybe update the post to avoid the mess... hint 4x spaces=code formatting.

Comment: ok - updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to find mapreduce.xml and modify the following number:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.mapper.inputprocessingrate</name>
  <value>**2000**</value>
</property>
```